# Reference AssemblyFileVersion in csproj file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Once my nant build has completed I'd like to rename the generated .exe file using a post-build command which is appended to the end of the projects .csproj file (within the Project element):

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).exe" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)\MyApplication-$(AssemblyFileVersion).exe" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

As you can see above, I am trying to rename the executable to: MyApplication-$(AssemblyFileVersion).exe however, this is obviously wrong, as the resulting executable is simply named: MyApplication-.exe (so the version I am trying to add at the end of the file name is missing).

I have defined the AssemblyFileInfoVersion in the AssemblyInfo.cs file as follows:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.5.1")]
```

So the question is: How can I access the AssemblyFileVersion in the csproj file of that same project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GetAssemblyIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164296.aspx) can get information about complied assemblies. The task output contain metadata entries about Version, PublicKeyToken, and Culture.

I used `$(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).exe` as the assembly file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AssembliesPath Include="$(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).exe" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="GetAssemblyInfo">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="@(AssembliesPath)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyInfo"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
</Target>
```

And then:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <GetAssemblyInfo />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).exe" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)\MyApplication-%(AssemblyInfo.Version).exe" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your answer :) ! However, the number generated is 0.0.0.0 instead of 1.5.1 (see above for an update of my question) - so it seems to not be accessing the AssemblyFileVersion but something else. Any ideas?

Comment: @Zainodis, if you set `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.5.1")]` you will get what you want. `GetAssemblyIdentity` only reads `AssemblyVersion`, not `AssemblyFileVersion`.

Comment: @LexLi actually I suspected that and tried it before posting my comment above, but even if I change that value, it still spits out the number 0.0.0.0 oO - could I be missing something?

Comment: I changed my post a bit, so you may want to try this that way. Also make sure that the assembly that describe the version is in fact `$(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).exe`.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply and thank you very much for updating your question. I followed your updated steps, but oddly enough I am getting a GetAssemblyInfo task not found. I am new to this, but what I gathered from the build output, could it be, that I must implement a corresponding task class as well? The error message also said, that another condition is for the task to be delcared in <UsingTask> within the project file. I'll try both things and see if it fixes the problem :)

Comment: Implementing the Task as a class opened up a whole new suit of issues xD - one of them being, that apparently ms build constantly removes my references to  Microsoft.Build.Utilities and Microsoft.Build.Framework oO ... So I have to re-add them after each failed build. It'll take some time until I can take another look at this, if you find a solution meanwhile, it would be nice if you could let me know - thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, I got it working, but using your original answer. I'll post your original answer as well and I'll accept your current answer as the solution, although that's not how I did it in the end and because my custom task wasn't recognized, despite registering it :/

Answer (score 2):

The following code is from ISun's original answer and this is actually how I ended up doing it in the end, as I had problems defining a custom task (ms build references were constantly auto-kicked and the build kept failing over and again).

As you can see from the comments under ISun's answer I always got the version 0.0.0.0 - despite having changed the version for AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyVersion to 1.0.0.0 by manually opening the AssemblyInfo.cs in a texteditor. I later read how to edit the AssemblyInfo.cs from my Visual Studio, here is how:

- Right-click on your project (that generates the exe file)
- Click on **Properties**
- Open the **Application tab** (first tab on the left) on the window that'll open
- You'll see fields for setting the Assembly name, Default namespace etc however to edit the 
  AssemblyInfo.cs, simply click on the Button called **Assembly Information** to the right

And for some reason - I have no clue why it suddenly worked, after I had put in all the information via the above method (using Visual Studio) ! When I first opened the AssemblyInfo.cs using the above way, all my fields were actually empty, despite them being filled in the actual file.

And now that I got the AssemblyInfo.cs to finally function correctly, I used ISun's original code to achieve my goal. By adding the following snippet just before the closing  tag in my project's **.csproj** file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).exe">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyInfo"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).exe" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)\MyApplication-%(AssemblyInfo.Version).exe" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```